# php, sessions, arrays - how to assign strign to the end of the session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have this small code , why it does not work and how to make it correctly ?

```
$temp = $_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i];
$temp += ',Medlemskort';
//$_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i] = $temp;
```

I am testing it with

```
?><script>alert('<?php echo  $_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i] ?>'+'----------'+'<?php echo $temp ?>');</script> <?php
```

And what i get is :

```
blbla,blll----------0
```

Whats wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String concatenation is done with **`.`** in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Try:

```
$temp .= ',Medlemskort';
```

Otherwise you perform addition, and if both strings don't start with numbers, they will be converted to `0` and `0 + 0 = 0` :)

Have a look at [*Type Juggling*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: :D thanks, stupid me... a lot of mess between javascript and php :D Thanks

Comment: @Black: I think I lot of us have been there :)

Comment: @BlackJ Simple solution is to make someone else do all that Javascript stuff ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's because += is an operator for adding integers, not strings. You want to concatenate strings (which is "."). Also, there is no need to create a temporary variable, only to overwrite the existing one. This should work:

```
$_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i] .= ',Medlemskort';
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrongly assign more things to the variable via `+`. You should use `.` instead.

```
$temp .= ',Medlemskort';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want $i to have temp's value, no need for the +=:

```
$temp = ""; // good habit to initialize before usage
$temp = $_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i];
$temp = ',Medlemskort';
$_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i] = $temp;
// or even save a $temp
 $_SESSION['contactPersonInterest'][$i] = ',Medlemskort';
```

Hope this makes sense, good-luck